# Wt Collapsible Menu Items

Tags: c++, wt

[Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) (pronounced as witty) is a C++ library for developing web applications.

It has it's own standard widgets like Menus, Trees, Tree Tables and [etc](http://webtoolkit.eu/widgets/).

The Question is if there are any Menu widgets with collapsible menu Items?(e.g. like WTreeTable but in WMenu fashion?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but worth a try.

You can create a `Wt::WMenu` with all collapsible `Wt::WPanel`s as its items and add a `Wt::WTreeTable` to each panel view. This may give you what you are looking for.